# Laravel 5 Eloquent related model return specific fields without ID

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have two models, **Fair** and **Coordinate**. Coordinate has many Fair's.

When retrieving the related **Coordinate** from **Fair**, I only want to return **Longitude** and **Latitude**, no timestamps or the ID.

When I run `$fairs = Fair::with('coordinates')->get();` The Coordinate relation is **Null**.

If I change the `select` method on the `belongsTo` in **Fair** model to `return $this->belongsTo('App\Coordinate', 'coordinate_id')->select(array('id', 'longitude', 'latitude'));`

The response is correct, but it includes the ID.

```
"coordinates":{
    "id": 1,
    "longitude":"-25.704571",
    "latitude":"59.145973"
},
```

Is there a way to use the **select** method without including the ID?

I found if I also add `protected $hidden = ['id'];` to the Coordinate model, the response I want is correct.

```
"coordinates":{
     "longitude":"-25.704571",
     "latitude":"59.145973"
 },
```

This doesn't seem like the correct way to do it.

**Fair:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Fair extends Model
{
    protected $dateFormat = 'c';

    public function coordinates()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Coordinate', 'coordinate_id')->select(array('longitude', 'latitude'));
    }
}
```

**Coordinate:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Coordinate extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['longitude', 'latitude'];

    public function fairs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Fair');
    }
}
```

Comment: The hidden property seems to me the correct way to exclude columns from the result

Comment: It would be correct if you wanted to exclude ID from the model completely, although not in every instance would you want to exclude it. Also, my question is asking why the select method doesn't work when you don't include the ID column.

Comment: instead of select try using get method $this->belongsTo('App\Coordinate', 'coordinate_id')->get(array('longitude', 'latitude'))

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
1.

```
$fairs = (new Fair)->get();
foreach($fairs as $fair){
    echo $fair->coordinates->longitude;
}
```

and
2.

```
$fairs = (new Fair)->with('coordinates')->get();
foreach($fairs as $fair){
    echo $fair->coordinates->longitude;
}
```

Difference is that 2. case use eager loading(queries optimisation) more on: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Laravel don't join by default(perform join query), it joins(perform join query) when you reference joined data like here "$fair->coordinates->longitude".

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Is there a way to use the select method without providing the id column?

Answer (score 0):

You could do with a closure to select just desired columns with eager loading with the `addSelect` method:

```
$posts = Fair::with(array('coordinates' => function($query)
{
    $query->addSelect(array('longitude', 'latitude'));
}))->get();
```

That way you don't have to hide the `id`column permanently from results but just for that specific query.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do it all in one query you can join and select

```
$data = Fair::query()
    ->join('coordinates','coordinates.id','=','fairs.coordinate_id')
    ->get(['fairs.*','coordinates.latitude','coordinates.longitude'])
```

If you use eager loading then you have no choice but to get the id because thats how eloquent maps the results, this way the result will just be part of the Fair attributes.